# Regular expression in javascript to find a group of word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string "Here I go again (1985)". The number within the bracket might not always be the same, therefore I want to find out a way to replace a match string from the opening bracket to the closing bracket. If I want to replace "(1985)" with another string, how can i do it using regular expression?

For example,

```
"Here I go again (1985)"
```

after manipulation should yield

```
"Here I Go again <b>(1985)</b>".
```

Comment: what if my string is something like "I have (2) cat(s)"

Comment: in that case, strictly 4 digits within the bracket should only give correct match, is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Hope it will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Its very accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
"Here I go again (1985)".replace(/(\(\d+\))/, '<b>$1</b>');
```

Output:

```
"Here I go again <b>(1985)</b>"
```

Comment: can you please tell me what does $1 mean in the answer?

Comment: `$1` refers to the first group in regex.

Answer (score 3):

Please find the below string

```
var s = "I am Spider Code (Stack Overflow) born in (1988)";
s = s.replace(/(\([\d{4})]+\))/, "<b>\$1</b>");
```

**Input**

I am Spider Code (Stack Overflow) born in (1988)

**Output**

I am Spider Code (Stack Overflow) born in **(1988)**

Comment: I'd have accepted it, but I can only accept one. However, this is very exact to what I want to achieve. Great help, and a lot of thanks to you too.

Comment: you can again accept it :) so that it may help other developer's who are facing the same issue and they can get correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Here i go again (1985)"

str = str.replace(/(\(\d+\))/, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex : `/(\([^)]+\))/`
And replace code : `"<b>\$1</b>"`

**Code :**

```
  var s="Here I go again (1985)" ; 
  console.log(s.replace(/(\([^)]+\))/,"<b>\$1</b>"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Here I go again <b>(1985)</b>
```

Check **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zJ0iB7)**